# Error 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' when get Admobpro Cordova plugin running with Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a project that envolves many other plugins, before i try to install admobpro, everything is working just fine!

After i install admobpro by using this command:  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro` , when i try to `ionic run android`, i'm getting this errors:
[image: error admobpro]

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you installed google repository in your sdk?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya yes